# How to Save/Reload data in vb.net after .exe close?

Tags: vb.net, save

I am new to vb.net, and this is my first project where I'm fairly certain there is an obvious answer that I just can't find.

**Problem:**  I have a list of a structure I have defined with many properties. I want to be able to edit and load that list with the values I have saved to it before hand after closing the program and loading it backup. What is the best way to do this?

This isn't a simple string or bool, otherwise I would use the user settings that is commonly suggested, in the project's properties. I've seen others that save it into an xml and take it back up, but I'm not inclined to do so since this is going to be distributed to others in mass. Since it's a complex structure, what's the commonly held preferred method?

**Example**

Here's a structure:

```
Structure animal
 Dim coloring as string 
 Dim vaccinesUpToDate as Boolean
 Dim species as string 
 Dim age as integer 
End structure
```

And there's a List(Of animal) that the user will add say 1 cat, 2 dogs, etc. I want it so that once the programs is closed after the user has added these, that structure will be saved to still have that 1 cat and 2 dogs with those settings so I can display them again. What's the best way to save the data in my program? 
Thanks!

Comment: If its going to be distributed in mass then the best thing to do would be to force the application to update when you change the variables. Keep the variabels saved locally(i would put it in your struct or another class) that way when you change the file, the application will update. IF you do not want to go that route, then the best thing to do would be to connect to a database and store these values.

Comment: There is always Settings.  if the data is in some nice NET construct (ie not a Struct), you could also likely serialize it.  If the user can change the values just use a small class to read/save using XMl or binary serializer.

Comment: I've heard binary serializer and XML before (I have no experience, so I'll probably need to look up a tutorial). Are there pros/cons of either in a commercial app?

Comment: @Jonny, the structures are so small, I was hoping to avoid a database since it appeared to not be that much memory.

Comment: database is good if you want people to save their stuff. Else the best is to have an xml file or a txt file in app data(its hidden in windows) with these variables. (sorry i misread(its 5 oclock here, want to go home)) have it saved locally with a txt file or xml file. You can even make a csv(which is the best IMO) because it can literally serve as a little database.

Comment: XML con: can edit in notepad  MS Bin con: large and slow and non trasportable ProtoBuf-Net: incredible.  These all only work on concrete, NET objects list List<T>, Classes etc.  If you are using Struct they may need extra work to get it to work.  a database is overkill especially if the app otherwise does not use a DB.  Serializing can be done in 3-5 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider serialization.  For this, a class is more in order than an old fashioned Struct:

```
<Serializable>
Class Animal
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Coloring As String
    Public Property VaccinesUpToDate As Boolean
    Public Property Species As String   
    Public Property DateOfBirth As DateTime

    Public ReadOnly Property Age As Integer
        Get
            If DateOfBirth <> DateTime.MinValue Then
                Return (DateTime.Now.Year - DateOfBirth.Year)
            Else
                Return 0   ' unknown
            End If
    End Get
    End Property

    ' many serializers require a simple CTor
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} ({1}, {2})", Name, Species, Age)
    End Function
End Class
```

The `ToString()` override can be important.  It is what will display if you add `Animal` objects to a `ListBox` e.g.: "Stripe (Gremlin, 27)"

```
Friend animalList As New List(of Animal)   ' a place to store animals

' create an animal
a = New Animal
a.Coloring = "Orange"
a.Species = "Feline"       ' should be an Enum maybe
a.Name = "Ziggy"
a.BirthDate = #2/11/2010#

animalList.Add(a)
' animalList(0) is now the Ziggy record. add as many as you like.
```

In more complex apps, you might write an `Animals` collection class.  In that case, the `List` might be internal and the collection could save/load the list.

```
Friend Sub SaveData(fileName as String)
    Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(fileName,
        IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)

        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        bf.Serialize(fs, animalList)
   End Using
End Sub

Friend Function LoadData(fileName as String) As List(Of Animal)
     Dim a As List(of Animal)
     Using fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
        a = CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), List(Of Animal))
    End Using
    Return a
End Function
```

XMLSerialization, ProtoBuf and even json are much the same syntax. For a small amount of data, a serialized list is an easy alternative to a database (and have many, many other uses, like a better Settings approach).

#### Calculated Fields as Properties

Notice that I added a `BirthDate` property and changed `Age` to calculate the result.  You should not save anything which can be easily calculated: in order to update the `Age` (or `VaccinesUpToDate`) you'd have to 'visit' each record, perform a calculation then save the result - which might be wrong in 24 hours.

The *reason* for exposing `Age` as a Property (rather than a function) is for data binding.  It is very common to use a `List<T>` as the `DataSource`:

```
animalsDGV.DataSource = myAnimals
```

The result will be a row for each animal with each *Property* as a column. `Fields` as in the original `Structure` won't show up. Nor would an `Age()` function display, wrapping the result as a readonly property displays it.  In a `PropertyGrid`, it will show disabled because it is RO.

#### Class versus Structure

So if a Structure using Properties will work, why use a Class instead?  From [Choosing Between Class and Struct on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx), **avoid** using a Structure unless the type meets all of the following:

1. It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.)
2. It has an instance size under 16 bytes
3. It is immutable
4. It will not have to be boxed frequently

`Animal` fails the first 3 points (while it is a local *item* it is not a *value* for #1).  It may also fail the last depending on how it is used.

Comment: My actual structure doesn't have age, but I used an animal as an example since my dog wanted to be involved. :D But, understood. Got to make sure all the properties meet their intended restraints.