# How to save data within the Application?

Tags: vb.net, save

I'm creating a basic To-do program. I want to save the list of tasks the user creates. Now I've tried with saving them as text files but I don't want it that way. I want it so that I can save the tasks the user creates within the program rather than external text files and then retrieve those saved files and display them in a text file.

Essentially I need a way to save data without needing to rely on databases.

A good example is GeeTeeDee. It seems to be saving its files and data etc. in the program within rather than external text file.(I'm assuming this because I can't seem find them. I could be wrong)

**Update**

I was doing a bit of searching can came across this: [Click here!!!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26740/Manage-Data-in-a-WinForms-Application-without-the)

But the problem is that I'm confused as to how this works. Is someone able to clear things for me? It would be GREATLY appreciated as it's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: You have to store the data somewhere - either a text file, database or some other persistent store mechanism.  Once the program terminates, any data in memory will be lost.

Comment: i agree with Tim, In my opinion without saving on `plain Text` file you can save them to xml file which is more convenient to read and write using `xml serailization`, or you can store values to `registry`

Comment: just because you cant find the files doesnt mean they arent doing so (programs do not write to the EXE). [this link might explain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379611.aspx) why you cant find them. My.Settings is one option. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23659023/1070452) shows how to serialize a small list of class objects which will work with small to medium data sets.  The specific answer depends on WHAT you are saving exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "code project" example saves the data at an external file with extension [*.brd] .

You can Use XmlSerializer to save and load your data from external xml file with extension xml,brd or anything else.

Try the code below, add into a form1 three buttons (Button1,Button2,Button3) and a DataGridView1, paste the code and Run.

1. press button  "add data dynamically" or/and  add,edit,delete row directlly from DataGridView1.
2. press Save data.
3. close and run programm
4. press Load data.

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO
Class Form1
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Button1.Text = "Load Data"
        Button2.Text = "add data dynamically"
        Button3.Text = "Save Data"
        'Create Dataset
        ds = CreateDataset()
        'Set DataGridView1 
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Person")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        LoadFromXMLfile("c:\temp\persons.xml")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        AddDataToDataSetDynamically(ds)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        SaveToXMLFile("c:\temp\persons.xml", ds)
    End Sub
    Private Function CreateDataset() As DataSet
        Dim dataset1 As New DataSet("Persons")
        Dim table1 As New DataTable("Person")
        table1.Columns.Add("Id")
        table1.Columns.Add("FName")
        table1.Columns.Add("Age")
        '...
        dataset1.Tables.Add(table1)
        Return dataset1
    End Function
    Private Sub AddDataToDataSetDynamically(d As DataSet)
        d.Tables("Person").Rows.Add(1, "Andrew", "46")
        d.Tables("Person").Rows.Add(2, "Nicky", "43")
        d.Tables("Person").Rows.Add(3, "Helen", "15")
    End Sub
    Private Sub SaveToXMLFile(filename As String, d As DataSet)
        Dim ser As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(DataSet))
        Dim writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(filename)
        ser.Serialize(writer, d)
        writer.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub LoadFromXMLfile(filename As String)
        If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
            Dim xmlSerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(ds.GetType)
            Dim readStream As FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)
            ds = CType(xmlSerializer.Deserialize(readStream), DataSet)
            readStream.Close()
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Person")
        Else
            MsgBox("file not found! add data and press save button first.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

add that code to **form1** and get the data to a textbox (add button4,textbox1)

```
    Private Function PrintRows(dataSet As DataSet) As String
        Dim s As String = ""
        Dim thisTable As DataTable
        For Each thisTable In dataSet.Tables
            Dim row As DataRow
            For Each row In thisTable.Rows
                Dim column As DataColumn
                For Each column In thisTable.Columns
                    s &= row(column) & " "
                Next column
                s &= vbCrLf
            Next row
        Next thisTable
        Return s
    End Function

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        TextBox1.Text = PrintRows(ds)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This made it a lot more easier.