# How to use own collections in application settings in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program in VB.NET and try to save different profiles via the application settings (project settings -> settings tab).

I created a `Profile` class and a collection class of that. If I choose this collection as settings type, I can add multiple objects with type `System.Object`, but I need to add my `Profile` object.

How can I add a collection of my `Profile` objects with the settings editor? Whats wrong with my code?

**Profile.vb**

```
Imports System.Configuration

<SettingsSerializeAs(Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)> _
Public Class Profile
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property ViewerCommand As String
    Public Property ViewerPath As String
    Public Property StartService As Boolean
    Public Property StopService As Boolean
End Class

<SettingsSerializeAs(Configuration.SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)> _
Public Class ProfileCollection
    Inherits CollectionBase

    Public Shadows Function Add(ByVal ProfileObject As Profile) As Profile
        MyBase.List.Add(ProfileObject)
        Return ProfileObject
    End Function

    Public Shadows Sub Remove(ByVal ProfileObject As Profile)
        MyBase.List.Remove(ProfileObject)
    End Sub

End Class
```

**A screenshot of the current behavior**

The type is `VNC_Manager.ProfileCollection` for the setting called "Profiles".
[image]

On the right side there should be Name, ViewerCommand, ...

If I use `VNC_Manager.Profile` for type, I also can't see Name, ViewerCommand... So there seems to be a problem with the `Profile` class(?)

Comment: I'd use `Collection(Of T)` rather than CollectionBase for the collection class.  See if that helps

Comment: But I can not inherit "collection(of T)". I think, this would work as type, not as inheritance class. I'm not sure if it's possible to change in that way.

Comment: Collection<T> is in System.Collections.ObjectModel.  It is a fair amount of work still just to get the VB App framework to serialize some data for you.  Once you have a working collection, it is easy to serialize the data yourself.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25319489/1070452) and [also this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25319489/1070452)