# How to create a new instance of a class when converting to it as a type vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, serialization

I have a Serializable class called SettingsForProgram this class contains a list of string called ServerList 
I am  using this class to save settings for myprogram (username , password , colors , etc..) but when i try to save a list the same way then add -or get- items from it i get object reference not set to instance of object so how can i create a new instance of the class when converting it

To understand what i mean here are some codes :

The class :

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class SettingsForProgram
Private Namev As String = ""
Private pwv As String = ""
Public LocationsList As New List(Of String)
Private Savev As New Boolean()
Public Property LoginName As String
    Get
        Return Namev
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Namev = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property LoginPassword As String
    Get
        Return pwv
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        pwv = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property SaveLogin As Boolean
    Get
        Return Savev
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        Savev = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Sub New()
    LocationsList = New List(Of String)
End Sub
End Class
```

To load settings:(where i want to initialize the new instance of the class)

```
public MySettings as new SettingsForProgram
Public Sub LoadSettings()
    Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter()
    Dim data As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(savepath)
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(data)
    MySettings = CType(formatter.Deserialize(ms), SettingsForProgram)
End Sub
```

To save settings :

```
Public Sub SaveSettings()
    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter()
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    If MySettings.LoginName = Nothing Then
        MySettings.LoginName = "name"
    ElseIf MySettings.LoginPassword = Nothing Then
        MySettings.LoginPassword = "password"
    End If
    bf.Serialize(ms, MySettings)
    Dim mySaveState As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
    File.WriteAllBytes(savepath, mySaveState)
End Sub
```

I made a quick test like this

button 1 : save

```
MySettings.LocationsList.AddRange({"test1", "test2", "test3"}) <<<< where i get the error
 SaveSettings()
```

button 2 : load

```
 LoadSettings()
  MsgBox(MySettings.LocationsList(1))
```

Comment: I believe your issue is that when LocationsList is serialized, it = "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]", not the values inside it. To fix the issue, you should create you own list and handle the serialization events to make it the values within the string. Do some searching on how to serialize collections or arrays.

Comment: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25319489/1070452) might help

Answer (score 0):

thanks to #Steve i now know the problem 
, the solution is to do like i did with name and password saving ,
just added this to the save Settings

```
If MySettings.LocationsList Is Nothing Then
        MySettings.LocationsList = New List(Of String)
        MySettings.LocationsList.Add("Location 1")
End If
```

and every thing worked

final code

```
Public Sub SaveSettings()
    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter()
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    If MySettings.LoginName = Nothing Then
        MySettings.LoginName = "name"
    ElseIf MySettings.LoginPassword = Nothing Then
        MySettings.LoginPassword = "password"
    End If
    If MySettings.LocationsList Is Nothing Then
        MySettings.LocationsList = New List(Of String)
        MySettings.LocationsList.Add("Location 1")
    End If
    bf.Serialize(ms, MySettings)
    Dim mySaveState As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
    File.WriteAllBytes(savepath, mySaveState)
End Sub
```