# How to read separate words from a text file?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, file-io

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to read separate words from a text file to put into an array in the program.

So say I have a text file of:

```
potatoes
bananas
oranges
```

I want to read from that text file and have those words indexed in an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to write to/read from a "settings" text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297365/how-to-write-to-read-from-a-settings-text-file)

Answer (score 2):

If, as in your example, each word is on a separate line, you can use the `ReadAllLines` method of the `File` class to create an array where each line of the file is an element of the array.

```
Dim words() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\MyFolder\MyFile.txt")
```

Comment: I like to split into a new list of string.

Comment: @I'mStartingToHateThisSite if you want a list instead of an array, you can just use `ToList`. `Dim words As List(Of String) = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\MyFolder\MyFile.txt").ToList`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub read_whole_file()
    Dim sFile As String, sWhole As String
    Dim v As Variant
    sFile = "C:\mytxtfile.txt"
    Open sFile For Input As #1
    sWhole = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
    Close #1
    v = Split(sWhole, vbNewLine)
End Sub
```

Replace only in function Split

Comment: That code will not compile in vb.net. It appears to be VB6 or VBA.