# Location to save custom settings text file?

Tags: vb.net, io

I have a VB.Net program that has a few custom settings that are saved in a text file. Right now the file is saved in "settings.txt" which saves in the bin folder. The problem is that this program gets published to my network so my coworkers can use it, and every time I roll out a new update their settings they've saved get deleted; it overwrites the file with a blank version of it. Is there another location that would be better for me to save the file? or is there a way (maybe through code?) to prevent the contents for each of my coworkers from getting deleted every time I publish an update?

```
Public Class Program
'global variables
Dim fileName As String = "settings.txt"
Private Sub Program_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
'code
Try
If File.Exists(fileName) = False Then
    File.Create(fileName)
End If
        ' Open the file using a stream reader.
        Using sr As New StreamReader(fileName)
            Dim line As String
            While (sr.EndOfStream = False)
                line = sr.ReadLine()
            End While
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
'rest of program
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is there something which rules out My.Settings?

Comment: To be more specific, it's a number of text and column filters for a DataGridView. Some of my coworkers don't need to see all 23 columns and/or 65 rows in there and have the choice to filter it down by column name and by what text is in a particular column. This would be far too complex to save in My.Settings. I tried an XML file earlier but get nowhere and found a text file to be easier.

Comment: To continue expanding on that, each "entry" in the text file is a list of all applied filters, then "ENDLIST" to end one filter list and start another. My coworkers can name their filter and access it from a dropdown as soon as they open the application.

Comment: Why don't you just safe the text you would safe into the text file into the settings as is. You could even safe it as a StringCollection already split into lines. This may not be what everyone expects a safe entry to look like. But there is nothing that stops you from using the entries in My.Settings like this.

Comment: Oh dear.  Serializing a class or list of type is much easier than reading and parsing a text file.  it takes maybe 3 lines of code to serialize and number of items to disk, and 3-5 to read them back.

Comment: See [how to write to/read from a “settings” text file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25297365/1070452)  andalso [How to Save/Reload data in vb.net after .exe close?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23659023)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to not send the settings.txt file in the updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a ClickOnce app, try this:

```
Friend fileName As String = String.Empty

With My.Application.Info
    fileName = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), .CompanyName, .ProductName, .Version.ToString, "Settings.txt")
End With
```

Comment: I think it's a ClickOnce application. One of my coworkers suggested using the AppData folder.