# Declare and and define Property in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have two Class and I want to save my data into arrays form text box like this:
**Students.Name(txtID.Text-1).MathMark = txtMark.Text**
but I get error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

my code is:

```
Dim StudentsNumber as Integer = txtstdnum.Text
Dim Students as New StudentsInf(StudentsNumber)

Students.Name(txtID.Text-1).MathMark = txtMark.Text


Public Class StudentsInf

    Private mName() As String

    Sub New(ByVal StudentNumbers As Integer)
        ReDim mName(StudentNumbers-1)
    End Sub

    Public Property Name(ByVal Index As Integer) As LessonsMark
        Get
            Return mName(Index)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As LessonsMark)
            mName(Index) = Value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class LessonsMark

    Private mMathMark() As Object

    Public Property MathMark() As Object
        Get
            Return mMathMark
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Object)
            mMathMark = Value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: rather than internal arrays, you could save each student to a `List(of Student)`; your code would be much easier to use and read

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Exactly I write this code to know about my problem, What's your idea about a easier code ?

Comment: a student class would be a name and the mathmark; studentS would be a List)Of Student)  to hold many student objects.

Comment: @Plutonix Yes,it's possible but I don't have only name in StudentInf Class, I need to write and read some another informations too, but I think about it.

Comment: it doesnt matter *what* is in student, it can have many many properties. your `StudentInf` is just a wrapper around an array pr set of arrays - it is inside out from how it is normally done today

Comment: @Plutonix Can I get a sample code ?

Comment: [see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23659023/1070452) for one,  it mainly deal with seruialization but uses a `List(of T)` in the example

Comment: I got it, that's useful, I didn't use that never before. Can I define that as a public ?

Comment: yes, but the default is Friend which is usually enough unless you are using it from a Class Lib.  the important part is keeping the data together for ONE student or animal or employee, then use a `List(Of T)` to hold a bunch of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
Private mName() As String
```

needs to be:

```
Private mName() As LessonsMark
```

then you have to create the objects in your constructor, something like:

```
Sub New(ByVal StudentNumbers As Integer)
  ReDim mName(StudentNumbers - 1)
  For i As Integer = 0 To StudentNumbers - 1
    mName(i) = New LessonsMark()
  Next
End Sub
```

then it looks like your LessonsMark class is declaring an array of objects when it looks like it should be just a string property:

```
Public Class LessonsMark
  Private mMathMark As String

  Public Property MathMark As String
    Get
      Return mMathMark
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
      mMathMark = Value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

Comment: When I use 'Dim Students as New StudentsInf(StudentsNumber)' in another module to read my datas again ... I can't. I lose my datas. what can I do ?

Comment: @farzad89 useing *new* creates a new instance, so you would have to reference the existing variable.

Comment: Exactly I want to write and read my datas for each student as a array, and yes when I useing _new_ it creates a new instance. What can I do ?

Comment: @farzad89 You would have to pass the Students array to whatever class or function you are calling.

Comment: That's not possible for me to pass the students array to a Class in every module. I need **Students.Name(ID).MathMark** as a public data ?

Comment: @farzad89 Then make it public shared, but that's a code smell.  Global variables lead to tough to debug errors and is widely considered a bad programming practice.