# Saving and loading a game in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, load, save

Is there away I can save or load a game a lot more easier than I have?

Saving Code

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\Pugio Cadite\CharacterInformation.txt", True)
file.WriteLine(charactername)
file.WriteLine(characterrace)
file.WriteLine(characterclass)
file.WriteLine(characterGender)
file.WriteLine(charactergold)
file.WriteLine(characterlevel)
file.Close()
```

and I have not yet wrote the load function.

Comment: You could use serialization.  Store all of this in a class and then use the built in serialization/deserialization methods.

Comment: it depends on what is being saved, but [serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23657131/1070452) could work

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'save the program variables
    Dim p As New ProgramVars
    p.Prop1 = "1"
    p.Prop2 = "2"
    p.Prop3 = "3"
    p.Prop4 = "4"
    Dim strFilename As String = "C:\Junk\Junk.xml"
    p.Save(strFilename)

    'load them into a different object
    Dim p2 As ProgramVars = ProgramVars.Load(strFilename)
    MsgBox(p2.Prop3)

  End Sub
End Class

<Serializable>
Public Class ProgramVars
  Property Prop1 As String
  Property Prop2 As String
  Property Prop3 As String
  Property Prop4 As String
  Sub Save(filename As String)
    Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(filename, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
      Dim xs As New XmlSerializer(GetType(ProgramVars))
      xs.Serialize(fs, Me)
    End Using
  End Sub

  Shared Function Load(filename As String) As ProgramVars
    Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(filename, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
      Dim xs As New XmlSerializer(GetType(ProgramVars))
      Return xs.Deserialize(fs)
    End Using
  End Function
End Class
```