# Deserialize list of objects from a file to be displayed

Tags: .net, vb.net, binaryformatter

Basically I have created a file that I store serialized data from an Object called **TravelRecord**. I have no issue serializing the data and storing it in the file using a **BinaryFormatter()**, and I have no issue retrieving the first record. I just want to retrieve all the records and display them in a ListBox.

Here's some of the relevant code:

```
     Private reader As New BinaryFormatter()
     Private input As FileStream
     input = New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

     Dim record = CType(reader.Deserialize(input), TravelRecord)
     RequestLst.items.Add(record.toString())
```

This works for returning the first record, but I want it to return all of them so I can iterate through them like the following:

```
 For Each r As TravelRecord In records
            RequestLst.Items.Add(r.ToString())
        Next
```

I know I'm probably missing something really simple, but everything I try causes RunTime errors. There may also be a better way to handle this.

Here is what the serialized data in the file looks like.

```
  ÿÿÿÿ          DTravelRequest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   TravelRequest.TravelRecord   ID FirstNameLastNamePurpose    StartDateEndDateAmount   System.Guid

   ýÿÿÿSystem.Guid   _a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_i_j_k           “ŸPªO½cùømFÚw   Steve   Robinson   Semianr  U¾Ó €æ©PÓ     @o@ @_@    ÿÿÿÿ          DTravelRequest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   TravelRequest.TravelRecord   ID    FirstNameLastNamePurpose    StartDateEndDateAmount   System.Guid

   ýÿÿÿSystem.Guid   _a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_i_j_k           æ;o˜ùéAÎÜ^pñÌ   jake      Kirkbride   Stuff  l«™  Ó €CøX,Ô     À^@    ÿÿÿÿ          DTravelRequest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   TravelRequest.TravelRecord   ID   FirstNameLastNamePurpose    StartDateEndDateAmount   System.Guid

   ýÿÿÿSystem.Guid   _a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_i_j_k           FP“¼Î«Gž¥5tuUš   steve    stevenson   vacation @áw%Ó @ˆ!?(Ó     @_@    ÿÿÿÿ          DTravelRequest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   TravelRequest.TravelRecord   ID  FirstNameLastNamePurpose    StartDateEndDateAmount   System.Guid

   ýÿÿÿSystem.Guid   _a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_i_j_k           ‹MÆoh#D–âÑQþ…P   Steve    Stevenson   Program €œN4)Ô €CøX,Ô     @_@    ÿÿÿÿ          DTravelRequest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   TravelRequest.TravelRecord   ID  FirstNameLastNamePurpose    StartDateEndDateAmount   System.Guid

   ýÿÿÿSystem.Guid   _a_b_c_d_e_f_g_h_i_j_k           k$ˆµ§FŠmÂ§Íüâ   George    Govern   Stuff €CøX,Ô €ê¡}/Ô      `@
```

It seems my issue is how do I read all of these and turn them into a collection so I can work with them.

Here is the code for the TravelRecord Class:

```
    <Serializable()>
    Public Class TravelRecord

    'Class fields
    Public ID As Guid
    Public FirstName As String
    Public LastName As String
    Public Purpose As String
    Public StartDate As Date
    Public EndDate As Date
    Public Amount As Double

    Public Sub New()
        MyClass.New(Guid.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty,
                    Nothing, Nothing, 0.0)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(id As Guid, fName As String, lName As String,
                   purpose As String, startDate As Date, endDate As Date,
                   amount As Double)
        MyClass.ID = id
        MyClass.FirstName = fName
        MyClass.LastName = lName
        MyClass.Purpose = purpose
        MyClass.StartDate = startDate
        MyClass.EndDate = endDate
        MyClass.Amount = amount
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0,-40}{1,-10}{2,-10}{3,-15}{4,12:d}{5,12:d}{6,12:C}", _
            ID, FirstName, LastName, Purpose, StartDate, EndDate, Amount)
    End Function
End Class
```

---

From comments:

The serialization code:

```
formatter.Serialize(output, travelRequest)
```

Where travelRequest is an instance of TravelRecord.

I might need to explain this better is all. The system is for a User to submit TravelRecords. The Serialization is setup to `Append` a new TravelRecord to the file to act as like a database. (This is a homework assignment I usually use SQL). The Deserialization is to read all of the entries in the File and display them in a summary ListBox.

The reason Deserialization is only getting one TravelRecord is because I don't know how to get all the TravelRecords out of the File.

Is there a way to get a count of how many items are in the serialized file so I can do a finite For loop or something

Comment: Is the output supposed to be a collection? If so then `Dim records = CType(reader.Deserialize(input), List(Of TravelRecord))`

Comment: When I try that I receive the following Unhandled Exception: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in TravelRequest.exe

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'TravelRequest.TravelRecord' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TravelRequest.TravelRecord]'. `

Comment: is TravelRecord a collection?  or does it contain a collection?  in the first block you treat it like one item, in the second as a list or collection

Comment: It is not a Collection. I am accessing a file that has 3 instances of TravelRecord, and I want to read those and put them in a Collection so I can display each of them.

Comment: It would be more helpful to see the TravelRecords class and/or the Serializing code.  It does look like there is 4 items there, but the deserialize code only creates 1 item.  If you set a breakpoint and hold the mouse over `record` does it look valid?

Comment: `formatter.Serialize(output, travelRequest)` Is the serialization code. It takes a single TravelRequest that gets passed in from a Form. Is there a better way to Serialize the data so I can access it as a collection later?

Comment: TravelRecord is one single item.  What is travelRequest?  *That* must be a collection of some sort.  I would urge you to change the public fields on that class to Properties

Comment: TravelRequest is just the name of the system/exe it is no other class or object. Oops. Well it is the name of the system but it is also an instance of the TravelRecord in this case as travelRequest.

Comment: `formatter.Serialize(output, travelRequest)` travelrequest is the EXE???

Comment: `Dim travelRequest As TravelRecord = New TravelRecord(id, FirstNameBox.Text,
                                              LastNameBox.Text, PurposeBox.Text,
                                              Convert.ToDateTime(StartDateBox.Text),
                                              Convert.ToDateTime(EndDateBox.Text),
                                              AmountBox.Text)` This is what **travelRequest** is.

Comment: Weird.  All your code looks like it is serializing and deserializing one item only, but the file does looks like there is more than one.  [here is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23659023/1070452) for a list(of T)

Comment: Also @Plutonix to your question above about putting a break point on `record`, yes it is valid and that works just fine. But it only returns the first instance of TravelRecord seen in the file. The user through the input form can put in any number of TravelRecords, and then want to see all of them in a listbox on another screen. My problem is I want to show all of them not just the first one in the File.

Comment: you are only writing and reading one item to that file (from the code here) so I dont know what that other stuff in the file is or how it got there.  It might be from earlier when you *did* have it set to work on a collection.  I am not sure if BF does File.Truncate for us or not

Comment: I might need to explain this better is all. The system is for a User to submit TravelRecords. The Serialization is setup to `Append` a new TravelRecord to the file to act as like a database. (This is a homework assignment I usually use SQL). The Deserialization is to read all of the entries in the File and display them in a summary ListBox. The reason Deserialization is only getting one TravelRecord is because I don't know how to get all the TravelRecords out of the File.

Comment: I wouldnt think to use FileMode.Append with a serializer.  It wont create a random access file.  The code you have is *not* to read them all, it is to read one.  Since you wrote them out one at a time, you will have to read them back the same way,  MUCH easier to just use a `List(of TravelRecord)`  (how would you delete record 7 of 9?)

Comment: My hands are tied as these were the assignment specifications. Is there a way to get a count of how many items are in the serialized file so I can do a finite `For` loop or something?

Comment: I updated your post with the relevant details here so I can post an answer...of sorts.  The assignment really specifies the BinaryFormatter with FileMode.Append, one record at a time?  What a useless skill

Comment: the Type data in the file will make it problematic to calculate how many records there are.  BF likely adds other "markers" which would throw it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write one record at a time:

```
formatter.Serialize(output, travelRequest)
```

so you will have to read back one record at a time.  The `BinaryFomratter` stores Type data along with the data (`TravelRecord`) so you cant just read it back as a collection (array or `List(of TravelRecord)` because there is no way it can convert from one Type to a collection Type (without some gyrations I am sure you dont want to undertake).  You can see the Type data in the file:

> TravelRequest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken...

The file wont be random access, so to get record 3 or find "Foo" you will have to do something similar (eg test for username = "Bob" and `Exit For`).  Standing in for `TravelRecord` is a class named NVP which I happen to have handy.

```
Function GetListofTravelRecords() As List(Of NVP)
    Dim tmpList As New List(Of NVP)
    Dim tmp As NVP

    Using fs As New FileStream("C:\Temp\nvplst.bin", FileMode.Open)
        Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter

        Do Until fs.Position >= fs.Length
            tmp = CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), NVP)
            tmpList.Add(tmp)
        Loop

    End Using
    Return tmpList

End Function
```

Usage and test:

```
Dim mylist = GetListofTravelRecords()

For Each item In mylist
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString)
Next
```

Output:

> ziggy (1)
>   zacky (2)
>   zoey (3)
>   ziggy (4)
>   zacky (5)

I had 11 things in there and they all made it back safely and in the same order.

---

Note to others, it is much easier to [serialize an entire collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23659023/1070452) and read it back *as* collection.

Comment: deleting a record will be next to impossible - you'd have to read them all into a collection or array, drop the one to delete then write them all back out

Comment: Thank you for all the time and effort Plutonix. I understand this is not an ideal situation or a good use of BF. After this weeks homework I'm hoping to be able to go back to Full stack web development and leave BF and Serialization alone!

Comment: BF and Serialization are fine...its the one at a time Append that is goofy