# Adding items to listbox from a struture file in vb with an if statement?

Tags: vb.net, file, if-statement, visual-studio-2012, listbox

PS: i have visual studio 2012 edition

Hey i have a file where i saved structure "personne" in a .txt file based on info the user gives me in a separate form now i need to search that file which eventually contains the info of several people (name, last name, sex, city ect..) for men.

The goal is to have a listbox showing the names and last names of all males in the file

The code works perfectly when i remove the "if p.sexe ="homme" " part but then it would list the names of all the people in the form, not just the males.
When i keep the condition and unidentified error occurs visual studio doesn't even tell me what it is. It just freezes until i close the app.

I'm relatively new to vb and don't understand the problem. any suggestions?

```
Public Class Form4
Private Sub cmdAfFiltre_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdAfFiltre.Click
    Dim a, i As Integer
    a = FreeFile()
    Dim p As Personne, L As Long
    Dim path As String
    path = "d:\miniprojet.txt"
    L = Len(p)
    FileOpen(a, path, OpenMode.Random, , , L)
    i = 0
    While Not EOF(a)

        FileGet(a, p, i + 1)
        If rdnHomme.Checked Then
           'the goal is to only add to the list when the "person"'s sexe is male 
           'homme means man
        If p.sexe = homme Then

                lstPersonne.Items.Add(p.nom & p.prenom)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    End While
    FileClose(a)
End Sub
```

Comment: You be much, much better off getting rid of those legacy VB File functions and using the NET versions.  Rather than using the file as random access, you could serialize an entire List(of Person) in 2-3 lines and read back the entire list as well.  Then just manage the underlying list.

Comment: [Example Binary Serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23659023/1070452)

Answer (score 0):

```
 If p.sexe = homme Then
    lstPersonne.Items.Add(p.nom & p.prenom)
    i = i + 1
 End If
```

should be

```
 If p.sexe = "homme" Then
    lstPersonne.Items.Add(p.nom & p.prenom)
    i = i + 1
 End If
```

I do agree with the other comments, you should move away from the random file access and use something like https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316730